# Catch External API Error Message as in Postman Body

Tags: c#, .net, api, error-handling

I am using the following code to complete an External API call.

```
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

  string JSONResult = null;
  var data = response.GetResponseStream();
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
  {
    JSONResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

When there is an exception on the external API, the request.GetResponse throws an error. However, I cannot get the message that is displayed, e.g.

```
{
        "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '<site>/Foo'.",
        "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Foo'."
 }
```

Whilst this is displayed in Fiddler and Postman, I cannot get this message anywhere when it is thrown as an exception.

How do I get this specific details when an error on an external API's call is made?

Comment: try { } catch (Exception ex) { throw ex }

Comment: @AGrammerPro unfortunately it would need a bit more work than that. See my answer.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the exception and then read the *response stream* of the exception. Reading the exception's response stream is the same as reading the response of the request. Here is how:

```
WebRequest request = 
WebRequest.Create("http://...");
WebResponse response = null; 
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
    if (webEx.Response != null)
    {
        using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // TODO: use JSON.net to parse this string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do not put all your code inside the above try block because you are only *try*(ing) and *catch*(ing) the `request.GetResponse()`. The rest of your code needs to go outside that try catch block so you can catch the exceptions from that code separately.